# Brownian motion and multi-scale stochastic processes

Tags: fluid-dynamics, renormalization, diffusion, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

The Stokes-Einstein equation for the diffusion coefficient of small colloidal particles in suspension is canonically derived under the assumption that the primary motion of the particle is translational. When considering the diffusion of anisotropic particles, rotation or "spin" of the particle is also relevant, and when considering the diffusion of a many-body (or "few-body") *cluster* of particles that are near each other, the relative motion of particles is relevant too.  This is made somewhat more interesting by the fact that anisotropic particles often undergo a steady rotation under translation in viscous media (think of how a corkscrew would move through molasses under gravity.)  I could imagine this effect being somewhat important in modeling the thermal behavior of anisotropic colloids, for example.

Can diffusion be decomposed into roughly independent or linearly coupled components, such as an *aggregate* diffusion constant set by the hydrodynamic radius of a particle together with various *internal* components from which the aggregate diffusion can be computed, and could this process be continued indefinitely (until some kind of tangle of interacting two- or one-plus-epsilon dimensional scale invariant field theories is reached describing the various thermally excited interfaces and boundaries)?

At larger length scales, the macroscopic movement of a colloid is often explained in terms of thermal collisions with individual water molecules at small length scales.  However, even if this were the sole source, one might expect to see similar thermal collisions driving colloid-shaped pockets (control volumes) of the ambient fluid, which in turn would carry each other and the colloid itself through advection.  So clearly there has to be another renormalization process at work, where 'microscopic collisions' includes random advection by neighboring pockets of fluid, or even the microscopic environment that the colloidal particle is embedded in.  Could it be that this renormalization process only "works" (i.e. preserves the scaling of Brownian motion) when the ambient fluid has the same scale invariance as Brownian motion itself?  (What if the diffusion process occurred instead in a fluid with some kind of ordered layer structure?)

Also, if the above considerations are accurate, could the "simple" process of Brownian motion of colloidal particles or complex elastoplastic particles (like biomolecules) be an example of a system whose renormalization group flow could be "chaotic" in a limited sense?